# How can I put a new connector on an RF cable?

Tags: tv-antenna, connectors

I bought a house not long ago, and the coax cable from the antenna that comes through the wall looks like it's been chewed or mangled somehow. It's missing the connector too.

I'm thinking about how I'll want to use this to get TV into this room. So I'll need to put a new end on. How do I do that?
[image: Image of rambly wire]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be looking for a coax compression tool. Something along these lines...

[image: Coax Compression Tool]

Comment: Do these put Belling Lee connectors onto the cable? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belling-Lee_connector

Comment: I don't believe so. Sadly, I don't recall ever seeing the type of connector you're referring to... The tool I posted is for standard coax connectors, in the U.S. There MAY be a similar tool for the connector type in your link.

Comment: Those connectors are all over the place here in the UK. But then, so are those coaxes. Probably what I'll do is crimp a coax on the end like you suggest, and then get an adaptor.

Comment: They do make screw on connectors that my cable provider loves to use, they should be much cheaper than buying tool.  I am a big fan of crimping, they hold much better.

Comment: Yes, "screw" on repair ends are another possibility but are prone to make bad connections. I've personally had bad luck with the screw on coax ends.